# Minimum font size issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

I've set up a label and in the label is some text. Now I want to set up the font that all the text fits in the label. I used for that minimum font size, because the label text changes every day. But suddendly it wont work. I'm doing something wrong?

Here my code:

```
CGRect infoLabelRect = CGRectMake(10, 250, 260, 350);


UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoLabelRect];
infoLabel.text = @"bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla";
infoLabel.numberOfLines = 9;
infoLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
infoLabel.minimumFontSize = 12;
infoLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
infoLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
infoLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
[infoLabel sizeToFit];
```

I tried what rmaddy sad but there's no text displayed.

Here is my code which doesnt work.
Any suggestions?

```
UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:infoLabelRect];
    NSString *text = @"bla bla bla";
    UIFont *font = nil;
    CGFloat points = 17;
    CGFloat maxHeight = infoLabel.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat textHeight;
    do {
        font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:points];
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(infoLabelRect.size.width, 100000);
        CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
        textHeight = textSize.height;
        points -= 1;
    } while (textHeight > maxHeight);

    infoLabel.font = font;
    infoLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    infoLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    infoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    infoLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    infoLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    [infoLabel sizeToFit];
    [contentView addSubview:infoLabel];
```

Comment: what does "wont work" mean? is it always fontSize 17? or is it truncating the text?

Comment: it is always fontsize 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `minimumFontSize` is only applicable to label's of one line. Multi-line or wrapping labels don't attempt to adjust the font size.

From the docs for `minimumFontSize`:

> The default value for this property is 0.0. If you enable font adjustment for the label, you should always increase this value. This property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1.

One solution is to make use of the `NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method to calculate the font size need to make the label's text fit in the allotted space.

Edit: Something like should work (this is not tested, could be typos):

```
NSString *text = @"hello";
UIFont *font = nil;
CGFloat points = 17;
CGFloat maxHeight = infoLabel.frame.size.height;
CGFloat textHeight;
do {
    font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:points];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(infoLabelRect.size.width, 100000);
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    textHeight = textSize.height;
    points -= 1;
} while (textHeight > maxHeight);

infoLabel.font = font;
```

Comment: do you have an example for me?

Comment: @NoahRaissi Have a little patience. I was busy typing up the code.

Comment: I got an error on "text sizeWithFront..." undecleared identifier...?!

Comment: Do I have to replace it with my label?

Comment: Replace `text` in my code with the label's text or whatever variable you may have that contains the text you use for the label.

Comment: I'm using label.text = ""; means a NSString but nothing works... sorry but I'm new at this. Could you make an example with the text "hello"?

Comment: houston we got a problem!! There is nothing displayed! :/

Comment: You meed to use the code I gave to determine the font based on the text and the desired label height. Use the rest of the code you had to setup the label.

Comment: You never set the label's text in the updated code. You still need the line `infoLabel.text = text;`.

Comment: Thank you bro. :D If I could I would give you uncountable thumbs up.